# Bash script md5sum

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i have problem

My input file:

```
user1 password1
user2 password2
```

How to get in output

```
user1 paassword1  d857ed4f845fce06fbc5bb76
user2 password2   e10adc3949ba59abbe56
```

I  use

```
md5=$(md5sum "$1" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
```

but I do not know what's next

Comment: Are you wanting the md5sum of  the username, the password, or the combination of the two?

Comment: As a reminder, the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48406703/edit) to include the information amasmiller has requested.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#! /bin/bash
while read -r user passwd ; do
    md5=$(printf %s "$passwd" | md5sum | cut -c1-32)
    printf '%s %s %s\n' "$user" "$passwd" "$md5"
done
```